# What is wrong with this if mechanism in python?

Tags: python

When I run it in Python 3.6 environment, I'll get an error saying; **'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'**

```
hours_Worked = input ("Enter the hours worked\n")
rate = 25.00
if hours_Worked > 40:
    grosspay = (40*rate) + ((hours_Worked-40) + (rate*1.5))
if hours_Worked <= 40:
        grosspay = hours_Worked * rate
print("Gross Pay: ", str(grosspay))
```

I can get the correct output in python 2.7 after changing the input seeking syntax.

What is wrong with this code? I don't understand!! I got to know that the error is with if-statement.

I'm new to python. Please help me.

Comment: `input()` returns a string in Python 3. You have to convert it with `float()` or `int()` into a number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the `input` to `int`. By default it returns a string.

**Ex:**

```
hours_Worked = int(input("Enter the hours worked\n"))
```